# Dynamics CRM DDL? - Easiest way to convey set of changes to another instance

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Pretty new to Dynamics CRM 2011.

I'm creating a data integration with Dynamics CRM using the services interface for another Customer.   The service interface works great, but there a handful of custom fields (attributes) we need to have added to their instance.   The customer won't give us temporary admin or even "Customizer" roles on their Dev/test instance to create the additional attributes.

We've tried describing in prose the changes we need them to make, but invariably it takes a day to go round trip in email, and some things get done correctly, while other fields will need small corrections after the first time they attempt the change.  (painful)

(1) Is there a way to export the schema changes in a **DDL** type script?   I know a little about "**solutions**" and I am trying to create one.  But for a small set of changes like this, a DDL script that they could examine and then run seems like the obvious solution.

I know there is excellent programmatic access to customizing Dynamics CRM.  (2) Is that an option for exporting schema changes, or is that not what it is for?

(3) If a "**Solution**" is my best bet here, are there any tips I should know about to make it simple and easy for everyone for this handful of new fields, relationships, and lookups?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) Direct changes to a CRM underlying schema are unsupported changes. Your DDL scripts might work, but being unsupported you lose the ability to get support form microsoft if you go down this road and you aren't gauranteed to work.

(2) Not supported. Same as above.

(3) Solutions are definitely the best bet here. A good introduction on what they do can be found here: http://www.dynamicscrmtrickbag.com/2011/05/28/dynamics-crm-2011-solutions-part-1/ . Some specific tips to your scenario:

- Make a new solution (you'll be able to modify it later). This will be your unmanaged solution.
- The key concept you'll be looking for is entity attributes. Make your modifications with the solution editor (Components->Entities->Fields) and save the solution.
- send them the solution to import either as a managed or unmanged solution, in your case unmanged might be prefered (so they can make tweaks and export their changes to send back to you), but managed ensures they dont muck it up. Pick a type and always send them that type.